# Three word domain name

Tags: domains, top-level-domains

I need to buy a new 3 word domain name. 
Which domain name is more worth or more preferred by users?

> my-example-domain.com

or

> myexampledomain.com

Thanks
Tom

Comment: more than 1 hypen is used especially by spammy sites